# Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 503 with rvest

Tags: r, http, rvest

I was trying to web scrape some reviews using R `rvest` package and actually succeded until I interrupted my session with the red stop button (going into details).

Then I started to get this error:

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 503

when using the function `read_html`

I'm pretty sure it's due to the interution but I have no idea what exactly happened! Please help, I didn't find any solution on the web.

If it can help, here's a piece of code that has been interrupted:

```
reviews_links <- rbindlist(apply(med_links, 1, function(url) { 
  url2 = read_html(paste('https://otzovik.com', url, sep = ""))   
  data.frame(url2 %>% html_nodes("h3 a") %>% html_attr("href"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)}),    
  fill = TRUE)
```

I also tried to restart either R and my computer - didn't help

**UPDATED**

Apparently, it was just the site blocking my requests. Solved this problem by using delays and changing user-agent from time to time.

Comment: Quite improbable that it is an Studio problem. Error 503 means that the server is having problems. 
In other words, it is not telling that you are not allowed to connect but rather that they can' t connect.
To check if the server is working, try to ping them. Or paste the whole target URL into a browser.

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez Oh, you're right. Other links are working just fine. I was silly not to check it. Thank you!

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez I tried to paste the link into my browser and there was a captcha to check if i'm a robot but then it worked all right. But in R I still getting that error